# How hard would it be to get some comms during reentry?

Tags: reentry, communication

As I type, a Crew Dragon is out of touch while it reenters. While I see how the plasma around the spaceship would make it very hard to communicate, I'm surprised that it is really impossible. How hard would it be to get a low bandwidth (say 1 kb/s) signal through using a more powerful and/or more highly tuned transceiver, or maybe a much longer wavelength?

Comment: From what I understand, there is less interference with signals going upward from a reentering capsule. So, satellite communication may be easier than direct ground links.

Comment: Yes, shuttle used upper s-band antennas to communicate with TDRS satellites during entry.

Comment: That probably works better on a winged reentry vehicle where the top is getting cooked less.

Comment: My idea at least for downlink was to modulate the plasma through an actuator that increases/decreases the trail intensity.

Comment: @SF.the plasma is a function of ambient air pressure, speed and shape of the capsule. How do you want to modulate the plasma?

Comment: @SF hmm, interesting; you could add what basically amounts to a subwoofer to an aerodynamic surface, and transmit very low bitrate messages like smoke signals

Comment: @uwe "and shape of the capsule" - extend/retract an ablative surface to increase/decrease the drag slightly or deflects the plasma in a bit different direction; the trail itself becoming a readable recording of the data like grove edge on a compact disk.

Comment: While the plasma is optically bright it may not be optically opaque; laser communications might work, but they'd have a challenge pointing a narrow beam if the spacecraft attitude varied too quickly

Comment: Physics is cruel and unyielding.

Comment: In all seriousness:  what would be the point?  Reentry is ballistic at this point.  There's absolutely nothing that could be achieved via comms.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's probably why it isn't done. Costs and risks outweighing benefits.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I guess telemetry to learn from disasters is probably the best real reason, although maybe a really tough flight recorder does that just as well. Otherwise, I suppose it's just to make it less stressful for all the humans, and to satisfy public curiousity.